# 404 ошибка после отката сайта на битриксе

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет!

После отката сайта началась проблема в каталоге. Подскажите кто-нибудь.

Ошибка 404 Not Found:

> The requested URL
> /catalog/micromachines/19/ was not
> found on this server.

Такой папки "19" не существует, так как это ID раздела сайта. Подскажите, как исправить?

**Обновление**

Я сделала откат файл htaccess не переименовывался.
Хотя я уже столько "телодвижений" сделала с этим каталогом. . .файл неоднократно менялся
Содержимое такое:

```
# Web Optimizer options 
<ifmodule mod_setenvif.c="">    
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html     
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip     
BrowserMatch SV1; !no_gzip  
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html 
</ifmodule>
Options +FollowSymLinks 
<ifmodule mod_mime.c="">    
AddEncoding gzip .gz    
AddEncoding deflate .df     
<filesmatch \.html\.(gz|df)$="">    ForceType text/html     </filesmatch>   
<filesmatch \.xml\.gz$="">  ForceType text/xml  </filesmatch>   
<filesmatch \.txt\.gz$="">  ForceType text/plain    </filesmatch>   
<filesmatch \.ico\.gz$="">  ForceType image/x-icon  </filesmatch>   
<filesmatch \.css\.gz$="">      ForceType text/css  </filesmatch>   
<filesmatch \.js\.gz$="">       ForceType application/x-javascript  </filesmatch>   
<filesmatch \.svg\.gz$="">      ForceType image/svg+xml     </filesmatch>   
<filesmatch \.ttf\.gz$="">      ForceType font/ttf  </filesmatch>   
<filesmatch \.otf\.gz$="">      ForceType font/otf  </filesmatch>   
<filesmatch \.eot\.gz$="">      ForceType application/vnd.ms-fontobject     </filesmatch> 
<filesmatch \.(rtf|rtx)\.gz$="">        ForceType text/richtext     </filesmatch>   
<filesmatch \.xsd\.gz$="">      ForceType text/xsd  </filesmatch>   
<filesmatch \.xsl\.gz$="">      ForceType text/xsl  </filesmatch>   
AddType text/css css    
AddType application/x-javascript js     
AddType text/html html htm  
AddType text/richtext rtf rtx   
AddType text/plain txt  
AddType text/xsd xsd    
AddType text/xsl xsl    
AddType text/xml xml    
AddType text/cache-manifest manifest    
AddType video/asf asf asx wax wmv wmx   
AddType video/avi avi   
AddType video/ogg ogg ogv   
AddType video/mp4 mp4 m4v   
AddType video/webm webm     
AddType video/divx divx     
AddType video/quicktime mov qt  
AddType video/mpeg mpeg mpg mpe     
AddType audio/midi mid midi     
AddType audio/mpeg mp3 m4a  
AddType audio/ogg ogg   
AddType audio/x-realaudio ra ram    
AddType audio/wav wav   
AddType audio/wma wma   
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz  
AddType image/bmp bmp 
AddType image/gif gif   
AddType image/x-icon ico    
AddType image/jpeg jpg jpeg jpe     
AddType image/png png   
AddType image/tiff tif tiff     
AddType font/ttf ttf    
AddType font/otf otf    
AddType font/x-woff woff    
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot   
AddType application/msword doc docx     
AddType application/x-msdownload exe    
AddType application/vnd.ms-access mdb   
AddType application/vnd.ms-project mpp  
AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint pot pps ppt pptx  
AddType application/vnd.ms-write wri    
AddType application/vnd.ms-excel xla xls xlsx xlt xlw   
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database odb     
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart odc    
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula odf  
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics odg     
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation odp     
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet ods  
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text odt     
AddType application/java class  
AddType application/x-gzip gzip     
AddType application/pdf pdf     
AddType application/x-shockwave-flash swf   
AddType application/x-tar tar 
AddType application/zip zip 
</ifmodule> 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule> 
# Web Optimizer end Options -Indexes
 ErrorDocument 404 /404.php php_value upload_max_filesize 32M 
#php_flag session.use_trans_sid off #php_value display_errors 1
 #php_flag allow_call_time_pass_reference 1 
<ifmodule mod_mime.c="">    AddType application/x-httpd-php .ico </ifmodule>
 <ifmodule mod_dir.c="">    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html </ifmodule>
 <ifmodule mod_expires.c="">    ExpiresActive on    ExpiresByType image/jpeg &quot;access plus 3 day&quot;  ExpiresByType image/gif &quot;access plus 3 day&quot; </ifmodule>
 # Web Optimizer end
```

Что еще можно сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Зайдите на страницу /catalog/, нажмите на панели "Изменить страницу", чтобы она открылась в визуальном редакторе, после чего нажмите кнопку "Сохранить". В общих случаях это должно помочь, т.к. это действие создаст правило для ЧПУ. Но лучше сначала сделайте копию файла /catalog/index.php, т.к. визуальный редактор битрикса не всегда ведет себя адекватно, особенно если на этой странице заложен какой-то нестандартный код.

Answer (score 1):

```
/bitrix/admin/urlrewrite_list.php?lang=ru
http://take.ms/XxEdK
```

Если восстанавливали, то `/.htaccess.restore` переименуйте, заменив  `/.htaccess`.

Comment: Обновила вопрос